# ForEach под капотом - от разработчика Яндекса. Переписала в песочницу со слайда - не работает

Tags: javascript, foreach

Всем привет!
Просматриваю слайды с курса "JavaScript, часть 1: основы и функции" Курсеры, за вторую неделю, автор: Чистяков Денис, руководитель службы разработки Яндекс.
Разбирается функция forEach "под капотом". Пытаюсь выполнить все, как показано на слайдах, в песочнице, но не получается. В чем ошибка?

```
  let tweet = [  
          { hashtags: ['wstdays'], likes: 16},
          { hashtags: ['html'], likes: 8},
          { hashtags: ['wstdays'], likes: 10},
          { likes: 7}
          ];
        
        let result = [];
        function forEach(callback){
          for (let i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
            callback(this[i], i);
          };
          function filterWts(tweet, index){
            let hashtags = tweet.hashtags;
            if (Array.isArray(hashtags) && hashtags.indexOf('wstdays') !== -1) {
             result.push(tweet)
            }
          }
        forEach(filterWts)
```

[image: скрин слайда курса]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в функции есть `this`, значит она предполагает вызов от объекта как метод. В JS `forEach` - это метод массива, поэтому там `this`-ом является массив. Поместите свою функцию в прототип массивов или вместо `this` используйте дополнительный аргумент у функции типа `forEach( arr, callback )`.

Другими словами, когда вы вызываете `forEach(filterWts)`, вы нигде не указываете, что работу нужно сделать с вашим массивом. В отличие от этого в JS `forEach` это явно указывается до точки перед `forEach`.